# Getting a specific "page" from the Wikipedia XML dump

Tags: php, wikipedia

OK, so this is what I need :

- I have downloaded and extracted the full Wikipedia XML dump (>40GB, single XML file)
- I need to retrieve one particular `<page>` element (e.g. the page for the entry "Italy")

How can I do this? (Preferably with PHP code or some existing tool)

Comment: @Dagon Well, obviously. The point is *how*? You see, I'm really afraid of dealing with such a huge amount of data : What about speed? (searching, given that there is no sorting, will definitely take quite long, nope?) Also, what about memory? (Obviously not loading the whole document into memory)

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the full content of the page will be sequentially located, revisions might be anywhere in the same file or even in different XML files.

Please use or the [web API's action=export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Exporting_pages) at worst [Special:Export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export). Not adding a link here because the output is huge.